# slide in-out html element

Tags: html, css

I am searching for something like a "sliding drawer" - however they all span across the entire height of the page.I would like the slide in-out to just occupy the space it needs - and not cover the entire page.I also googled for hamburger menu on similar lines.

I guess I found out the element which I need.Please refer the screenshot below.

My ask is : 
What is the element called so that I can search and develop my own version of it.Any pointer will be a great help.

https://www.templatemonster.com/blog/responsive-sliding-drawer-menu-lightbox-effect/

[image]

Comment: It is div with css position set to fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

trying this

**[[demo]](http://jsfiddle.net/P8D22/17/)**

**html**

```
<div class="slideOutTab">
    <a href="http://facebook.com">Like Us on Facebook</a>
</div>
```

**css**

```
div.slideOutTab {
    position: fixed;
    width: 150px;
    height: 43px;
    top: 200px;
    left: -107px;
}

div.slideOutTab a {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-indent: -999em;
    background: 0 0 url('http://s9.postimg.org/okyi00edn/fb_like_us.gif') no-repeat;
}

div.slideOutTab a:hover {
    background-position: 0 -43px;
}
```

Comment: Why use Jquery?

Answer (score 0):

You can search for:
Sliding panel, fixed position panel, fixed sliding panel

At least you can start from those search terms and find more stuff as you delve deeper into the examples.

I made a 2 minute search using the above terms and I found a lot of examples that might help you. Give it a shot!

Comment: This really helped my way out.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try with `pure css`

```css
div.slideOutTab {
    position: fixed;
    width: 150px;
    height: 43px;
    top: 100px;
    left: -107px;
    transition-duration:1s;
    -ms-transition-duration:1s;
    -webkit-transition-duration:1s;
    -moz-transition-duration:1s;
}

div.slideOutTab a {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-indent: -999em;
    background: 0 0 url('http://s9.postimg.org/okyi00edn/fb_like_us.gif') no-repeat;
}

div.slideOutTab:hover {
    background-position: 0 -43px;
    left:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="slideOutTab">
    <a href="http://facebook.com">Like Us on Facebook</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Your example in the snippet is off the screen.

Comment: @AndrewBone am sorry dear for (Roll back). i didn't see that